# What is the best approach for achieving DI / testability in Unity development?

Tags: unity, c#, software-engineering

Sorry for the fairly open-ended question, but I'm hoping I can get some insight on how to tackle automated testing in Unity.  I've been quite surprised to not find a "definitive" approach on Google considering how popular Unity is.  In my experience, DI is vital to being able to write decent unit tests, but Unity doesn't seem well equipped for it considering we can't even use our own constructors on game objects.

I've found a few third-party tools that relate to this like [Zenject](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject) and [StrangeIoC](https://github.com/strangeioc/strangeioc), but nothing that seems very well maintained.  I can't imagine that the big AAA companies using Unity are building on top of a tool that last released in 2013.  If I were to work at such a company, what tools / patterns would I see the "real" guys using for testing?

Failing to find a tool for DI, I was thinking I could hack it in myself with some sort of ObjectGetter that game objects would call in their `Awake` methods to get the references they use:

```
public class ObjectGetter
{
    public Mock<Player> MockPlayer = new();

    public Player Player
    {
        get
        {
#if TESTING
            return MockPlayer.Object;
#endif
            return GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Player>();
        }
    };
}
```

I don't love using directives nor do I like imagining how big such a class would become for a large project, but this approach would at least let me write decent tests, right?

Comment: My wild amateur guess is that maybe the smaller popularity of DI in Unity is related to its inspector/serialization partially covering that need.

Comment: True.  Unity kind of bakes in IoC, which probably helps a lot of devs write better code even if unknowingly.  I just wish I could capitalize on it in some way for tests.

Comment: I have no experience in AAA projects actually,but I have to say, in my experience, the importance of unit testing in game testing is very low. Unit tests are only used for some low-level modules such as math, networking.etc. What we do more often is some automated performance testing and compatibility testing. For game-play, there may be a custom testing framework(based on image recognition or AI), fully serving a single project. Maybe that's why there's so little information about it. : ) hope it helps.